# Wall follower algorithm in Prolog

Tags: algorithm, prolog

I want to implement left-hand wall follower maze solving algorithm in Prolog language. I'm a full beginner in Prolog and haven't found anything on web regarding wall follower algorithm in Prolog.

Logic should be:
[image]

Right hand wall follower:
[image: right hand wall follower]

Comment: It is not sufficient to post your homework, you need to put some effort in it.

Comment: You might find something useful if you look for depth-first search.